# Why does Message+ randomly pop up on my processes on Kali?

Tags: networking, security, process, kali-linux

I watch my network using "top" and I notice message+ keeps randomly popping up for about 1-2 seconds then disappears. What is this and why is this happening? I can't find anything on it.

Comment: message+ means truncated user messagebus means dbus-daemon uses cpu sometimes. But without more context or knowing if there's an actual problem...